Shorthand URLs for Images results in post-blocking error when writing a Post or Editing a post with existing shorthand URLs for Images
Across the SE Sites, you can use // to replace https:// for URLs in posts to shorten a URL. An example of this is this link (look at this post's source to see it).
However, if you try this with an image, you will get an error saying:

All image URLs must start with https://


This prevents you from submitting the post. Furthermore, if a previously existing post has images linked in this manner, if you attempt to edit the post, it will force you to update all the image URLs present in the post to contain https://.  I don't know if this is a side effect from transitioning to the new image hosting service, or a new bug of some sort that was introduced elsewhere. It seems only image URLs enforce this.

This question may be a duplicate of Url protocol should not be required for image links.

@Jeremy ahh yes.  It seems so, though that post doesn't point out that writing new posts and linking an image this way also doesn't work.  Similar enough though to say its a dupe.
